# How to get all columns from first table when there is no matching column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

My requirement is to retrieve all the employee names from `employees` table and if there are no matching rows in `employee` table then employee name should be displayed along with the count as 0

```
CREATE TABLE #EMPLOYEES
(
    employeeId int,
    employeename varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEES VALUES (1,'Dinesh Alla')
INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEES VALUES (2,'ram')
INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEES VALUES (3,'Lakshmi')
INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEES VALUES (4,'sumanth')

CREATE TABLE #LOGS
(
    entityID int,
    EntityCode int,
    employeeID int
)

INSERT INTO #LOGS VALUES (1,201,1)
INSERT INTO #LOGS VALUES (1,201,1)
INSERT INTO #LOGS VALUES (1,201,1)
INSERT INTO #LOGS VALUES (1,201,1)
INSERT INTO #LOGS VALUES (1,201,1)


SELECT 
    te.employeeID, employeeName, 
    COUNT(ISNULL(entityCode, 0)) AS caseEntryCount
FROM 
    #EMPLOYEES Te 
LEFT JOIN 
    #LOGS Tee ON ISNULL(TE.employeeID,0) = ISNULL(Tee.employeeID,0) --OR entityEmployeeID IS NULL
WHERE 
    entityCode = 201 
GROUP BY 
    te.employeeID, employeename, entityCode
ORDER BY 
    employeeID
```

Check the below image of my output.

[image]

But my expected output would be:

```
employeeID      employeeName        caseEntry
1               Dinesh Alla         5
2               ram                 0
3               Lakshmi             0
4               sumanth             0
```

Comment: Why there are two tags sql-server-2008 and sql-server-2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT te.employeeID, employeeName, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #LOGS Tee
    WHERE Te.employeeID = Tee.employeeID AND Tee.entityCode = 201) AS caseEntryCount
FROM #EMPLOYEES Te 
ORDER BY Te.employeeID
```

You can rewrite your query with a LEFT OUTER JOIN using a GROUP BY but is more slow than a simple query on main table with a subquery for count in the selection list field

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT  e.*
  , COUNT(l.entityID) AS CaseEntry
FROM    #EMPLOYEES e
    LEFT JOIN #LOGS l
    ON l.employeeID = e.employeeId
GROUP BY e.employeeId
  , e.employeename
  , l.EntityCode
ORDER BY e.employeeId;
```

Try to avoid using ORDER BY if the order doesn't matter. That would give you better performance of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ISNULL in the join, just join then use an IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause. Something like this;

```
SELECT te.employeeID
    ,employeeName
    ,COUNT(entityCode) AS caseEntryCount
FROM #EMPLOYEES Te
LEFT JOIN #LOGS Tee ON TE.employeeID = Tee.employeeID --OR entityEmployeeID IS NULL
WHERE entityCode = 201
OR entityCode IS NULL
GROUP BY te.employeeID
    ,employeename
    ,entityCode
ORDER BY employeeID
```

It's also best practice to use the relevant table alias on all fields, not just the ones that are ambiguous. This will make your code much clearer and easier to read.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I've just updated the code that should meet your needs.